# The name of a 2-D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am learning pointers and arrays in C and Here is a question that confused me for a while:

So the name of a 1D int array is a constant pointer to **int**, which points to the first element in that array. So when we evaluate the name of a 1D array, we should get the address of the first element in the array.

For a 2D int array, the array name is a pointer to the first array of **int**. So what will be the value of a 2D int array's name? I think it should be the address of the first array in this 2D array. But how is the address of an array defined in C? Is it just the address of the first element in that array?

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3). An array is not a pointer and a pointer is not an array, but on access, an array is converted to a pointer to the first element subject to the 4-exceptions listed in the link.

Comment: Sorry, I think I don't make myself clear enough here. I actually understand that an array is not a pointer. In my question, what I actually mean is that when the name of an array is used in an expression, the compiler will generate the pointer constant.

Comment: People can be led to believe the name is a pointer in the same way that the name of a function is a pointer. You cannot for instance pass it as a pointer parameter in the same way a function name might be passed to qsort() ?

Answer (score 5):

> So the name of a 1D int array is a constant pointer to int

This is wrong, and it is often taught badly. An array is an array. Here is some code for analogy:

```
int x = 5;
double d = x + 1.2;
```

In the second line `x` is *converted to* `double` for purposes of addition. This does not change `x` which is still an `int`, the result of conversion is "temporary" and only exists until the addition is finished.   The conversion is demanded by the conditions of the `+` operator that both arithmetic operands must be brought to a common type (`double` in this case).

In the array case, say we have `char *p = arrayname + 1` , then `arrayname` is still an array. But it is converted to a temporary pointer so that the addition can occur (the `+` operator requires this, it can add a pointer and an integer). The temporary pointer points to the first element of the array, but it is not correct to say that the temporary pointer *is* the array.

Most operators invoke this conversion of an array to a temporary pointer, but some do not.  So it is not correct to say that `arrayname` is a pointer because it may be used with an operator that does not convert the array to a pointer, e.g. `sizeof arrayname`.

The result of converting an array to a pointer is a pointer to the first element of that array. This is always true even if the first element is itself an array.

> But how is the address of an array defined in C? Is it just the address of the first element in that array?

No. Every variable has an address, this applies to arrays and non-arrays. If you understand the address of an `int` then you also understand the address of a 2x2 array of `char`.

Answer (score 5):

Let's clear up some things:

```
int a = 24;
```

The above is many things:

- a declaration: we declare a variable named `a` of type `int`.
- a definition: an object of type `int` is created.
- an initialization: this object is initialized with the value `24`

So let's recap: an object of type `int` is created with the value `24` and the variable `a` *names* it.

Now let's apply the same to the following:

```
int a1[3] = {0, 1, 2};
```

- a declaration: we declare a variable named `a1` of type `int[3]` (aka array of 3 integers).
- a definition: an object of type "array of 3 integers" is created
- an initialization: the object is initialized with `{0, 1, 2}`

The variable `a1` names that object.

> So the name of a 1D int array is a constant pointer to int, which
>   points to the first element in that array.

Wrong. I know you might have been told or read this, but it is incorrect. An array is **not** a pointer!! Arrays and pointers are different types. That being said, for convenience and historical reasons, in most situations (but not all!) an array decays to a pointer to the first element:

```
int a1[3] = {0, 1, 2};
int* p = a1; // here a1 decays to a pointer to its first element
```

In the above snippet `p` points to the element `0` of the array `a1`

You can view 2D or 3D or nD array the same way:

```
T a2[3] = {l0, l1, l2};
```

Let's say `T` is a type. The above is an "array of 3 `T`s".

- if `T` is `int` then we have `int a2[3] = {0, 1, 2}` - an array of 3 integers. We call this an 1D int array.
- but if `T` is `int[2]` then the above becomes `int a2[3][2] = {{00, 01}, {10, 11}, {20, 21}}` - you can see it as "an array of 3 `T`s" or "an array of 3 `int[2]`" or "an array of 3 arrays of 2 integers".

And we can apply the same decaying rule:

```
int a2[3][2] = {{00, 01}, {10, 11}, {20, 21}};

int (*p2)[2] = a2; // a2 decays to a pointer to its first element.
                   // Its first element is an array of 2 int.
                   // So a2 decays to `int (*)[2]` -  a pointer to an array of two elements.
```

In the above `a2` points to the element `{00, 01}` of the array.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation makes sense to me!

Answer (score 3):

An arrays name is not a pointer. In most cases when the name of an array is used, it gets implicitly *converted* to a pointer to its first element, it is said, that the array decays into a pointer.

The name of an array does not decay to a pointer when it is the argument of the address-of operator (`&`), the `sizeof`-operator and when a string literal (which is an array of some character type) is used to initialize an array *).

That said, a two-dimensional arrays

```
T arr[COLS][ROWS];
```

first element is an array of type `T[ROWS]`. So `arr` decays to a pointer of type `T(*)[ROWS]` which points to the first element of `arr`.

---

*) If you might want to add that arrays also do not decay when they're the operand of the `_Alignof`-operator or read that somewhere else:

@EricPostpischi: Arrays cannot be operands of `_Alignof`. Including `_Alignof` in the exceptions for array conversion was an error in the C 2011 standard. `_Alignof` operands can only be types, not expressions.

Answer (score 2):

When a 2D array decays to a pointer, you have a pointer to an array.  Here's an example of what this would look like:

```
int arr[5][6];
int (*p)[6] = arr;
```

Answer (score 1):

An array is not a pointer. An array's name, when used in an expression, "decays" into a pointer to the first element.

Strictly speaking, C only has one-dimensional arrays, and a 2D array is really just an array of arrays.

1D array:

- The first element of `int arr [x]`, is an `int`.
- When `arr` is used in an expression, you get a pointer to that element, `int*`.
- When doing pointer arithmetic on this pointer, each item has the size of the first element = `sizeof(arr[0])`.

2D array:

- The first element of `int arr [x][y]` is an `int [y]`.
- When `arr` is used in an expression, you get a pointer to that element, `int (*)[y]`.
- When doing pointer arithmetic on this pointer, each item has the size of the first element = `sizeof(arr[0])`.

So it's the same rule. The `int(*)[y]` *array pointer* follows the same rules of pointer arithmetic as the ordinary pointer. But you can de-reference it one step further to get individual `int` in the array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

> "So what will be the value of a 2D int array's name?"
>
> "I actually understand that an array is not a pointer. In my question,
> what I actually mean is that when the name of an array is used in an
> expression, the compiler will generate the pointer constant."

You have to be careful here. As a follow-on to your comment below your question, there are nuances in how the array/pointer conversion rules apply that effect the `type` that results from the conversion. That will dictate whether and how you can use the array name in an expression.

> "... the compiler will generate the pointer constant."

*No.* The compiler does not generate a pointer constant, the compiler follows [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3). When the array name is used in an expression, the expression is evaluated with the address that results from the conversion of the array to a pointer (subject to the 4-exceptions stated in paragraph 3).

The rule regarding array/pointer conversion does not depend on number of dimensions, the rule is applied the same regardless. **However**, the `type` *of the pointer that results from the conversion* **does** depend on the number of array dimensions. That is critical and that will dictate whether your use of the array name is valid.

One way to help cement what is happening in the conversion is take it step-by-step. Start with a 1D array and work your way up.

**6.3.2.1 - 1D Array Conversion To Pointer On Access**

When you have a simple array, e.g.

```
int array[10];
```

On access to array, is converted to a pointer to the first element, e.g., the *address of* the element, `&array[0]`. (which is simply a *pointer to* `int`, or with formal type `int *`)

**6.3.2.1 - 2D Array Conversion To Pointer On Access**

With a 2D array, rule applies just the same, e.g.

```
int array[10][10];
```

Here `array`, a 2D array, is essentially an array of 10 - `int[10]` arrays (an array of 1D arrays). On access `array[10][10]` is converted to a pointer to the first array of `10-int` in exactly the same manner, `&array[0][0]` (which results in *a pointer to an array of* `int[10]` or with formal type `int (*)[10]`) It is not a *pointer-to-pointer* (e.g. `int**`), it is very specifically a pointer to an array of `int[10]`.

(**note** the important difference between `int *[10]` (an **array** *of 10 pointers* which on access will become a pointer-to-pointer) and `int (*)[10]` (a **pointer** *to array of 10* `int`))

**Answer**

*"So ... the value of a 2D int array's name when used in an expression"* -- is the address of the first 1D **array** of integers that make up the 2D array with formal type `int (*)[N]` (where `N` is the number of elements per-row).

**Nuance In How The Standard Is Applied**

The type is critical for the proper use of the array name. With a 2D array, the resulting address is a pointer to an *array*. What results if you dereference that pointer? (*Answer:* an **array**) What happens when you access that **array** through the derefernced pointer? (hint: the conversion on access rules apply again). You must know what the pointer type resulting from the conversion will be in order to properly use the array name in an expression.

**An Example May Help**

Or it may not, but working with the pointer types that result from the array access and pointer conversion may help things sink in. Below, the example declares a simple `4x3` 2D array of `int`. It then declares a pointer (`p`) of proper type to allow the array name to be used in an expression assigning the array address to the pointer. The pointer initialized with the array name is then used to further initialize an integer pointer (`ip`) to the first element in the first array.

The example then outputs the address for each element, and then using the pointer `p` outputs the address of the beginning of each row-array that makes up the 2D array. Finally the code enters a validation loop comparing the addresses of each element by (1) array index, (2) the address held by pointer `p` using an offset, and (3) address held by `ip`. The purpose being the use of each of the different pointers resulting from the expression assigning the array name to then reference each element and ensuring the addresses held by each pointer agree.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    
    int array[ ][3] = { {1, 2, 3},      /* 2D array values */
                        {3, 4, 5},
                        {5, 6, 7},
                        {7, 8, 9} },
        (*p)[3] = array,                /* pointer to array */
        *ip = *p;                       /* integer poiner */
    size_t  size = sizeof array,
            nele = size / sizeof **array,
            nrow = size / sizeof *array,
            ncol = sizeof *array / sizeof **array;
    
    printf ("2D array statistics:\n\n"
            "  size: %zu  (bytes)\n  nele: %zu  (ints)\n"
            "  nrow: %zu\n  ncol: %zu\n",
            size, nele, nrow, ncol);
    
    puts ("\naddress of each array element:\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < ncol; j++)
            printf ("  %p", (void*)&array[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }
    
    puts ("\naddress of each 1D array:\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nrow; i++)
        printf ("  %p\n", (void*)p[i]);
    
    puts ("\nvalidating each array element address by index & pointer:\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < ncol; j++) {
            if (ip != &array[i][j] || ip != *p + j) {
                fprintf (stderr, "address validation failed for "
                        "array[%zu][%zu]\n(%p != %p || %p != %p)\n",
                        i, j, (void*)ip, (void*)&array[i][j],
                        (void*)ip, (void*)(p + j));
                return 1;
            }
            ip++;
        }
        p++;
    }
    puts ("  done!");

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_2d_access
2D array statistics:

  size: 48  (bytes)
  nele: 12  (ints)
  nrow: 4
  ncol: 3

address of each array element:

  0x7ffe7c9a9780  0x7ffe7c9a9784  0x7ffe7c9a9788
  0x7ffe7c9a978c  0x7ffe7c9a9790  0x7ffe7c9a9794
  0x7ffe7c9a9798  0x7ffe7c9a979c  0x7ffe7c9a97a0
  0x7ffe7c9a97a4  0x7ffe7c9a97a8  0x7ffe7c9a97ac

address of each 1D array:

  0x7ffe7c9a9780
  0x7ffe7c9a978c
  0x7ffe7c9a9798
  0x7ffe7c9a97a4

validating each array element address by index & pointer:

  done!
```

Let me know if that helped and whether you have any further questions.